# displaying results on websocket client page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I just started with web socket and I keep running websocket server and calling it using client from index.html.

Server returns me json of video link and I want to display this video on client page.

When I run this index.html as client(calling javascript given below) it keep writing `$('.pixabay-images').append(pixabay_content)` rathen on click event.

In response I receive links, which I put in video display, but it shows nothing.

Console.log() displays the received response:

```
{"video_link": [{"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/QcIy9NiNbmo", "title": "Taylor Swift - Bad Blood ft. Kendrick Lamar"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B5nPN9B3c5w", "title": "My Favourite Animal | Dialogue Promo 4 | Sardaarji | Diljit Dosanjh | Jaswinder Bhalla"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VLpkuU7pNg", "title": "Veervaar | Sardaarji | Diljit Dosanjh | Neeru Bajwa | Mandy Takhar | Releasing 26th June"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/pY6cQTyk5oY", "title": "Here Comes Vinnie | Disney's ABCD 2 | Shraddha Kapoor"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XZCHyUpxfNA", "title": "YTV: Delhi on Sex Ed., Parents, Porn & Condoms Etc."}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/j1uy3TlanSk", "title": "Visa | Sharry Maan | Full Official Video | Yaar Anmulle Records 2015"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/YzF0e304rbU", "title": "GUJJU DIL DHADAKNE DO"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Fr_qNbCy8Y", "title": "This Dubsmash By Instagram Girl Will Leave You Stunned - She Is Awesome"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/e7VkRj_KYI4", "title": "\"\\u0932\\u0935\\u0932\\u0940 \\u0906\\u0917\\u0902\\u0924\\u0941\\u0915\" | Lovely Visitor Ke Sath Romance | HINDI HOT SHORT MOVIES/FILM"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jyNdlcLlCN0", "title": "Lana kisses Dolph Ziggler: Raw, May 18, 2015"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/bV2GklFBaT8", "title": "Happy B'day | ABCD 2 | Varun Dhawan - Shraddha Kapoor | Sachin - Jigar | D. Soldierz"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/66q2fmLWMCI", "title": "Hamari Adhuri Kahani - Hasi Song Video | Emraan | Vidya"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9ZsRQNUQ8Vo", "title": "Blank Space | Mental Manadhil Mashup - Vidya"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VLf_wVp_KXI", "title": "Premam - Malayalam Movie Song - Ithu Puthan Kalam | Nivin Pauly , Alphonse Puthren , Anwar Rasheed |"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/s7sSjAwORp0", "title": "Baahubali Jukebox | Prabhas, Anushka Shetty, Rana Daggubati, Tamannaah Bhatia"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/gcQKclaZ0UI", "title": "Uppu Karuvadu official Teaser"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TENkHYWYnAc", "title": "Hindi Movie | Shola Bai | Sapna, Amit Pachori | Hot Scene"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zF6sF85yV9s", "title": "'Selfie Le Le Re' VIDEO Song | Bajrangi Bhaijaan | Salman Khan | T-Series"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/AuuX2j14NBg", "title": "Drishyam - Official Trailer | Starring Ajay Devgn, Tabu & Shriya Saran"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VzjU3GF9ZBs", "title": "Kaisi Yeh Yaariaan - Episode 221"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/d5y2MJEUtQM", "title": "New Punjabi Songs 2015 | DENGU VS PENDU | MANPREET GILL feat. RUHANI SHARMA | Punjabi Songs 2015"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_VDqTzzh7So", "title": "Meri Aashiqui Tum Se Hi - 12th June 2015 - \\u092e\\u0947\\u0930\\u0940 \\u0906\\u0936\\u093f\\u0915\\u0940 \\u0924\\u0941\\u092e \\u0938\\u0947 \\u0939\\u0940 - Full Episode (HD)"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/a23GO0NXOtg", "title": "Katti Batti Trailer | Imran Khan & Kangana Ranaut | In Cinemas Sept.18"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ef27m5ocK6Q", "title": "ANOUK - BOLD IS BEAUTIFUL | THE VISIT"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mU9CB5nut1Y", "title": "Bollywood Actress Rekha Hot Bed Room Scene"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/QuRSCU0tOKs", "title": "Brothers Official Trailer | Akshay Kumar, Sidharth Malhotra, Jackie Shroff and Jacqueline Fernandez"}, {"url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/sOEg_YZQsTI", "title": "Baahubali Trailer || Prabhas, Rana Daggubati, Anushka, Tamannaah || Bahubali Trailer"}]}
```

display.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (!("WebSocket" in window)) {
    alert("Your browser does not support web sockets");
  }else{
    setup();
    createWebSocket();
  }
  function showServerResponse(response){

                console.log(response )            
                var pixabay_content = ''
                pixabay_content += '<br><b>Todays Trending Youtube videos </b><br><br>'
                pixabay_content += '<ul class="rig columns-2">'
                count = 1
                for(x in response['video_link'])
                { 
                    console.log(response['video_link'][x])
                    //pixabay_content +=  '<li> <img src="' + response['video_link'][x]+'" /> </li>'
                    pixabay_content +='<li> <iframe width="420" height="345" padding="5px" src="'+response['video_link'][x]['url']+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>'
                    if (count >= 4) {
                        break
                    }
                    count = count + 1
                }
                pixabay_content += '</ul>'
                $('.pixabay-images').append(pixabay_content)
  } 
  var connection;
  var myInterval;
  var host = "ws://192.168.1.141:8888/ws";
    // event handlers for websocket
  var attempts = 1; 
  function createWebSocket () {
    connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/ws"); 
    connection.onopen = function () {
      // reset the tries back to 1 since we have a new connection opened.
      attempts = 1; 
      // ...Your app's logic...
    }
    connection.onmessage = function(msg){
      showServerResponse(msg.data);
    }
    connection.onclose = function () {
      var time = generateInterval(attempts);
      showServerResponse("The connection has been closed.");
      console.log(time)
      setTimeout(function () {
          // We've tried to reconnect so increment the attempts by 1
          attempts++;
          // Connection has closed so try to reconnect every 10 seconds.
          createWebSocket(); 
      }, time);
    }
  }
  function generateInterval(k) {
    return 2000;
  }
  function setup(){
    var $txt = $("#data");
    var $btnSend = $("#sendtext");
    $txt.focus();
    // event handlers for UI
    $btnSend.on('click',function(){
      var text = $txt.val();
      if(text == ""){
        return;
      }
      connection.send(text);
      $txt.val("");    
    });
    $txt.keypress(function(evt){
      if(evt.which == 13){
        $btnSend.click();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebSockets Client</title>  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://192.168.1.141/js/display.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Enter text to send to the websocket server:-->
<div id="send">
    <input type="text" id="data" size="100"/><br>
    <input type="button" id="sendtext" value="send text"/>
            <div class="pixabay-images">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you want to display it ? web socket have event that can you manage to your response.

Comment: @viyancs: I want to display only when `sendtext` button clicked

Comment: then you should understand how to use your websocket to emit data to server and then catch the response